# How to play HLS audio stream in SoundManager 2

Tags: javascript, streaming, html5-audio, soundmanager2

I need to play some audio streams but I can't get HLS (Apple Cuppertino HTTP Live Streaming) to play in HTML5 within SoundManager 2.

Is there some alternatives to play HLS streams via web? (not only with iOS devices)

Comment: I see a github project that seems to do something like play m3u8 streaming with SoundManager 2, but appears to be a WIP...
https://github.com/creativeprogramming/soundmanager2-livem3u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SoundManager 2 can't play HLS streams, as the author says:

> (...) SM2 aims to be a "simple" library in terms of supporting basic sound playback (...)

After some research and tests, I'll go with [MediaElementJS](http://mediaelementjs.com/), a very nice project for supporting a lot of audio and video formats and codecs, with HLS implementation from [flashls](http://flashls.org/), RTMP support and many others.